# C++ How to implement friend operator overload defined in a namespace?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, friend

This class should use cout to print.

header

```
#pragma once
#ifndef Operator_Overload_h
#define Operator_Overload_h
#include <iostream>
namespace OperatorOverload {
    class CustomType {
    public:
        int value;
        friend const bool operator<(const CustomType&, const CustomType&);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const CustomType&);
    };
}
#endif
```

cpp

```
#include "OperatorOverload.h"
using namespace OperatorOverload;
using namespace std;


const bool OperatorOverload::operator<(const CustomType& left, const CustomType& right) {
    return left.value < right.value;
}

ostream& OperatorOverload::operator<<(ostream& os, const CustomType& c) {
    os << c.value;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    CustomType ct1, ct2;
    ct1.value = 1;
    ct2.value = 2;
    std::cout << "ct1 < ct2 = " << (ct1 < ct2) << "\n";
    std::cout << ct1 << "\n";
}
```

**Error**

> Error  C2039   '<<': is not a member of 'OperatorOverload'

> Error  C2593   'operator <<' is ambiguous

But operator< works. and if I replace operator<< with:

```
namespace OperatorOverload {
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CustomType& c) {
        os << c.value;
        return os;
    }
}
```

It's working. But I don't know exactly how this happens.

Why does operator < work, but operator << doesn't?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `using namespace OperatorOverload;` is just using namespace, not defining it.

Comment: Which compiler is not accepting your code? I think it is well-formed.

Comment: I use visual studio 2019

Comment: @neikyon Are you compiling with C++20/C++latest enabled or in conformance mode (`/permissive-`)? It seems that this specific MSVC version (if I matched it up correctly) has a bug in these circumstances. With the next version it works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/TGnd49Gbx

Comment: @273K OP is using qualified names to define the friend function, so it should be fine that they didn't open up the namespace scope. It is impossible to declare a function with qualified name in this way, but defining an already declared function should be fine.

Comment: Unrelated side note: Top-level `const` on a non-class return type of a function has effectively no effect at all. I don't know what you expect `const bool` to do differently than `bool`, but it isn't doing that.

Comment: @user17732522 oh, I use visual studio 2019 16.11.24. I will do it in another version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug specific to Visual Studio 2019 16.11 (MSVC 19.29) in conformance mode (`/permissive-` or `/std:c++20`/`/std:c++latest`).

In all other (prior or later) versions I tested and in non-conformance mode, the code compiles fine.

I don't see anything wrong with your code. It is not allowed to use a qualified name to declare a new function into a namespace. But you are trying to define a function that has already been declared in the namespace. That should be fine, even if the function is not visible to usual lookup (at least this seems quite clear to me in the current standard draft). The compiler should accept it.

The workaround you suggest at the end of your question is however the more common approach to defining friend functions anyway.